# Lucene Index cleanup in Cassandra

Tags: indexing, cassandra, lucene

We are using Lucene index in one Cassandra Table. As and when Cassandra data (With TWCS compaction for expired tombstone) gets removed,we could see index cleanup is not happening automatically.What is the best way for Lucene Index clanup in cassandra.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com instead. But don't be concerned, I'm just letting you know for future reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an index that Cassandra knows about (and the nodetool option exists in your version) then you can use 'nodetool rebuild_index' to clean up the index:
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/tools/nodetool/rebuild_index.html#rebuild_index

Otherwise, you can delete all the documents in the current index, then reindex, which should also do the trick.
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/reindexing.html